# Unable to write entire output in a text file

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

In the below function after doing some operations to print few words after some processing,i wish to print all the output words in a file,however rather than 4 words which are being produced as output only 2 are being written in the file words.txt.

```
def morsePartialDecode(inputStringList):
    with open('words.txt','w') as wordfile:
        message_received = inputStringList
        message_received = ' '.join(inputStringList)
        for i in range(len(message_received)):
            x = 'x'
            y = '.'
            message = message_received.replace(x, y)
        message1 = message.split(",")
        message_conv = morseDecode(message1)
        print message_conv
        print >> wordfile, (message_conv)

        for i in range(len(message_received)):
            x = 'x'
            y = '-'
            message = message_received.replace(x, y)
        message2 = message.split(",")
        message_converted = morseDecode(message2)
        print >> wordfile, (message_converted)
    wordfile.close()
    return message_converted
```

As an output of the function i am getting the the words:

```
EESE
TTDT
SAIFE
DMNCT
```

However in the file only SAIFE and DMNCT are written.Where did it went wrong.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would restructure the flow a little. For example, you have here a function `morsePartialDecode` that returns `message_converted`: let it just do that, and have the file-writing logic be done outside. It's not clear to me why you are writing to file both `message_conv` and then `message_converted`, yet only returning `message_converted`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to close the file if you're using a with statement if python.

You're opening the file in "w" mode, which means that every time you open it, the whole file will be destroyed. Try opening it in append mode.

edit:
Also, I would take a look at the CSV module. It has some great use cases here.